# Merge dsl job shells in just one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have this step

```
 def createJob(def jobName,
          def branchName) {


    job(jobName) {

      steps {
        shell('export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1')
        shell('$(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)')
        shell('docker build -t builder -f ./images/'+branchName+'/Dockerfile .')
        shell('docker tag -f '+branchName+':latest *******.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'+branchName+':latest')
        shell('docker push *********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'+branchName+':latest)')
    }
  }
}
```

How can I just add all those in just one shell?

I tried this way

```
   shell( '''
            export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
            $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)
            docker build -t builder -f ./images/'+branchName+'/Dockerfile .
           ''')
```

But then the variable branchName it´s treated as string. 
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes instead, which support interpolation (single quotes and single triple quotes do not). Then you can use `${}` to insert variables in the string

```
shell( """
          export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
          $(aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1)
          docker build -t builder -f ./images/${branchName}/Dockerfile .
         """)
```

For more information see the [groovy documentation on string interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation).